# Adding re-type email and check it if the email match

Tags: custom-field, customization, user-registration

I want to add email field on the registration page and check it if the two email that the user input matched or not.

I am using eshop theme by templatic.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This plugin may be exactly what you're looking for:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/register-plus/

Optionally, you may opt to create your own registration page in Wordpress from scratch. This guide will help you:

http://www.tutorialstag.com/create-custom-wordpress-registration-page.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. But my theme has a built in registration page and can't figure out which one to edit in the core files. I already installed register plus to add some extra fields but I am having trouble adding another email fields since my theme has already populated it and I want to add and check if the email that the user input matched. As an additional question, how can i make the last name rewuired. Thanks again for your immediate response

Comment: If its in the theme , then there is no reason to edit the core files, what theme are you using?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery would be the "proper" way to do it, but I am not that ofay with it, but it is possible to do in php like so

```
if($_POST['email'] == $_POST['email_conf']){
    //stuff to do on success
} else {
    //stuff to do on failure
}
```

Comment: Note that server-side validation (PHP) is a _must_.